# Service freezing the UI

Tags: android, service

I have a service which counts steps from the sensor data. It's a continuously running service. My service is running and also doing the desired task but my main problem is its freezing my UI. How can I update the UI without freezing it.

Here is my service class:

```
public class StepCounterService extends Service {
    private static final String LOG_TAG = "ForegroundService";

    public static Boolean FLAG = false;

    private SensorManager mSensorManager;
    private StepDetector detector;

    private PowerManager mPowerManager;
    private WakeLock mWakeLock;


    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        startServiceForeground(intent, flags, startId);


        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate();
        new StepCountManager(this);


        FLAG = true;

        Log.e("Service_Started", "");
        detector = new StepDetector(this);


        mSensorManager = (SensorManager) this.getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);

        mSensorManager.registerListener(detector,
                mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER),
                SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);


        mPowerManager = (PowerManager) this
                .getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
        mWakeLock = mPowerManager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.SCREEN_DIM_WAKE_LOCK
                | PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP, "S");
        mWakeLock.acquire();
        reloadSettings();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onDestroy();
        FLAG = false;
        if (detector != null) {
            mSensorManager.unregisterListener(detector);
        }

        if (mWakeLock != null) {
            mWakeLock.release();
        }

        Log.e("Service_destroyed", "");
    }

    public void reloadSettings() {

        if (detector != null) {
            detector.setSensitivity(
                    Float.valueOf("10")
            );
        }


    }

    @Override
    public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent) {
        super.onTaskRemoved(rootIntent);
        Intent restartService = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                this.getClass());
        restartService.setPackage(getPackageName());
        PendingIntent restartServicePI = PendingIntent.getService(
                getApplicationContext(), 1, restartService,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

        //Restart the service once it has been killed android

        ((AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE))
                .set(AlarmManager.RTC, System.currentTimeMillis() + 1000, PendingIntent
                        .getService(this, 3, new Intent(this, StepCounterService.class), 0));

    }

    public int startServiceForeground(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, HomeActivity.class);
        notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP| Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setContentTitle("Mobiefit Walk")
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setOngoing(true)
                .build();
        NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        mNotificationManager.notify(300, notification);
        Notification n;

        startForeground(300, notification);

        return START_STICKY;
    }


}
```

And here is my UpdateStepCount method which is declare in an Interface class and I am implementing it in seperate class:

```
public void UpdateStepCount(final int steps) {
        if (Target_Goal == 0) {
            Target_Goal = 10000;
        }
        resetData(steps);

        Log.i("Narendra", "Total Steps:::" + String.valueOf(total_steps) + "::Steps::" + steps + "::getlast count:" + MobieFitWalkApp.getInstance().getLastStepCount());
        total_steps = steps - MobieFitWalkApp.getInstance().getLastStepCount();
        Log.i("getDistance",String.valueOf(Utilities.convertKilometersToMeters(getDistance(total_steps))));
        Log.i("CountCalories",String.valueOf(countCalories(total_steps)));
       // sessionDetails = SummaryManager.singleton().getLastFreeWalkData((Activity) mContext);

       // getFreeWalkData(total_steps);

        updateNotification(total_steps);
        if (needToStore) {

            if (dbController != null) {
                if (dbController.isTodayDataPresent(getCurrentDate())) {
                    //we need to get data from db
                    //calibrate previous and current data
                    //we need to write code for update data in db

                    dbController.updateSteps(String.valueOf(getDistance(total_steps)), String.valueOf(""), String.valueOf(total_steps), String.valueOf((Utilities.round(countCalories(total_steps), 2))));
                    needToStore = false;
                } else {
                    //insert new row
                    storeStepsDataInDb(total_steps);
                    needToStore = false;

                }
            }
            //call back will take total_steps,kcal,distance
            if (updateUI != null) {
                updateUI.UpdateBackgroundStepsUI(total_steps, getDistance(total_steps), countCalories(total_steps));
            }


            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    // Log.i("xxx", "Sensor changed");
                    needToStore = true;

                }
            }, 1000);
        }

    }
```

Can Someone tell me how can I stop my UI from getting freeze.

Comment: Use AsyncTask with in IntentService

Comment: IntentService is a base class for Services that handle asynchronous requests (expressed as Intents) on demand. Clients send requests through startService(Intent) calls; the service is started as needed, handles each Intent in turn using a worker thread, and stops itself when it runs out of work. So IntentService spawns a worker thread. You can just use Handler mHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()); dispatch messages on UI thread

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Service is **always run in the main thread you can call it ui thread** so when ever you perform long running task inside service it will block the ui thread because its run on the main thread and you are trying long running operation on the same thread **so if you really want to use service with long running task than you have option make an asynTask or thread inside your serivce** and perform all such operation in the asyncTask or thread.

**Second solution you can use IntentService.** IntentService runs in worker thread also called as background thread so you need not bother about maintaining asynctask etc and it guarantee your ui will never block

Answer (score 0):

If performing long operations in ui thread then do that processes in some background thread(Async task)

Answer (score 0):

You have to consider that `Service` works on `Main Thread`. Instead of using `Service` you can go for `IntentService` which works on another thread.

Possible case of freezing UI is your `Service` may be performing long running operation.

Answer (score 0):

If you are performing long operation in service, consider using HandlerThread, AsyncTask or IntentService, or Thread to perform long running task.

Answer (score 0):

[Android Services](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html)

> Caution: **A service runs in the main thread of its hosting process**; the service does not create its own thread and does not run in a separate process unless you specify otherwise. If your service is going to perform any CPU-intensive work or blocking operations, such as MP3 playback or networking, **you should create a new thread within the service to complete that work**. By using a separate thread, you can reduce the risk of Application Not Responding (ANR) errors, and the application's main thread can remain dedicated to user interaction with your activities.